# How to reduce the cross section of a beech profile

Tags: woodworking, hardwood

What I have: A planed beech square 20 mm by 20 mm, length is 1 meter.

What I want: A number of short (5 or 6 cm) pieces, but with a reduced cross section of only 20 mm by 16 mm. I could reduce the cross section of the whole piece, then cut it into smaller pieces, or I could reduce the cross section after cutting – both would be fine.

So essentially, I have to cut off 4 millimeters. How and with what tools can I do this?

The goal is to make the base of a wooden toy train car (like the black parts in [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Brio_train_on_tracks.jpg)). I'm open to other suggestions like glueing something together from smaller profiles; however, I found no fitting smaller profiles either and am somewhat wary about the stability of that.

Comment: Try the Woodworking stack; it's a better fit there than here and they're more likely to give you a range of answers. Include a photo of the profile showing what you need to trim off it. Explaining what you are actually trying to accomplish may also help, since there may be other ways to achieve the same results.

Comment: Almost any cutting tool including sand paper will do.  What tools do you have?  Do not recommend the sand paper.

Comment: @keshlam I was unaware there was a dedicated Woodworking SE. Maybe the question can be migrated. I'll add some details about what I want to achieve.

Comment: @crip659 Well, I have a gent's saw and a fretsaw (the latter is probably not a good idea).

Comment: Either should work, but the gent's saw should make straighter cuts.  Would cut a tiny bit over(17mm) to sand/cut to final size.  Buying other saws not recommended for one off job(unless lotto ticket wins).

Comment: Find a friend with a tablesaw, belt sander, thickness planer, bandsaw or even a router. I'd never attack this problem with a handsaw.

Comment: A fine handsaw can do it, but other tools may be easier. It's really a matter of what you think you have enough control over and have on hand or are willing to invest in. I mean, you can do fine work with a hatchet, but that takes a lot of practice and is probably not preferred given alternatives.

Comment: 5 minutes or less with a ***sharp*** hand plane (or a power jointer, or a table saw...but those cost more and take up more space and like to eat fingers more.) Well, you really should also use a marking gauge so you know where you're cutting *to* with the plane.